Pure CSS - Responsive div depending on added text
I have this angular material code:
<mat-form-field>
   <div class="mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined mdc-text-field--invalid">...</div>
   <div class="mat-mdc-form-field-subscript-wrapper mat-mdc-form-field-bottom-align">
      <div class="mat-mdc-form-field-error-wrapper">
         <mat-error class="mat-mdc-form-field-error mat-mdc-form-field-bottom-align">
            Your username must be at least 8 characters long and should not contain spaces and the following characters \ &lt; &gt; ;
         </mat-error>
      </div>
   </div>
</mat-form-field>

and what I would like to do is that when error message is displayed adapt the height of the "mat-mdc-form-field-subscript-wrapper" div to the height of the error message. Any idea?
This is what I have

This is what I want


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

For dynamic adjustment, you need to make the error message, from absolute to relative positioning and ensure the parent container is display: flex. Since it's absolute positioned the parent cannot take the dimensions of the child, hence this issue.
SCSS:
.example-container {
  .mat-mdc-form-field-subscript-wrapper {
    display: flex;
  }
  .mat-mdc-form-field-hint-wrapper,
  .mat-mdc-form-field-error-wrapper {
    position: relative;
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

This is the simplest way, you have to add bottom margin, to adjust for the long text.
SCSS:
.example-container {
  .first {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
}

HTML:
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field class="first">
    <mat-label>Enter your email</mat-label>
    <input
      ...

Stackblitz Demo
